# Django: save(commit=False) on formset CBV is triggering customized model save() actions

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm using CBV CreateView to display a couple of pages with formsets to the user.

When the model behind a given formset/CreateView is a common one (it will became clearer later), everything works fine using the following logic on the view:

```
class Create(CreateView):
    ...

    def form_valid(self, formset):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for instance in instances:
            instance.user = self.request.user
            instance.save()

        return super(Create, self).form_valid(formset)
```

However, on one of the models, I had to add extra actions to the model save() method. Namely, I need to create child objects when the parents are saved. Something like:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    ...
        
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.child_set.create(...., *args, **kwargs)
```

In this particular case, the child object is being created twice and I believe that the formset.save(commit=False) is the culprit.

I tried replacing the child_set.create() for

```
        child = Child(...parameters, parent=self)
        child.save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But it yields the same result. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**`.form_valid(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_valid) of a [**`CreateView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView), will call `.save()` on the `form`, and this will thus invoke a new round of saving all objects.

You can set the `.user` of the instances, and then let the `CreateView` save these instances. This thus means that you implement this as:

```
class Create(CreateView):
    # …

    def form_valid(self, formset):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for instance in instances:
            instance.user = self.request.user
            # no instance.save()
        #                  ↓ this will save the instances
        return super().form_valid(formset)
```

That being said, it might be better to work with a [**`.get_or_create(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) over a [**`.create(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#create), since now you will create a `Child` object *each* time you save the `Parent` object, which is likely not the intended effect.